# Best way to call third-party API from code-pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

**I am just starting creating my code-pipeline and I want to create an action that will make API calls to Cloudflare**. What is the best way to do that?

I guess I can simply make this API calls (write this commands) using CodeBuild, but is there an easier way to make this API calls? Maybe using Lambda or something else? Sorry if the question is too general and uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeBuild or Lambda should work well for this. Lambda would probably work out slightly cheaper, but if you're not running your pipeline that often the difference won't add up to much.

If you decide to go with Lambda you can find details on how to do that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html

Comment: Thank you a lot! It would be great if you could help with another problem. I can't get a full understanding of custom and non-custom actions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059912/lambda-function-never-succeeds-in-codepipeline).